# Can a CWinApp be placed in a DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, winapi, legacy

I'm updating some legacy apps to Visual Studio 10 and am in linker hell. All of these DLLs derive classes from CWinApp and use AfxGetApp() to get access to the object. When I link the DLLs I get unresolved externals that look like global static objects that would get pulled in by a normal app's main():

```
Shell.lib(SHELL.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct CRuntimeClass const CException::classCException" (?classCException@CException@@2UCRuntimeClass@@B)
Shell.lib(SHELL.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct CRuntimeClass const CFrameWnd::classCFrameWnd" (?classCFrameWnd@CFrameWnd@@2UCRuntimeClass@@B)
Shell.lib(SHELL.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class CRect const CFrameWnd::rectDefault" (?rectDefault@CFrameWnd@@2VCRect@@B)
```

My current combination of ignore default libraries and additional libraries (the method you can easily google to find the answer to linker hell) is: msvcprtd.lib,mfc100d.lib,mfcs100d.lib,libcmtd.lib

When I add nafxcwd.lib (the mfc library), these three external symbols resolve but I end up with a bunch of other duplicate symbols (requiring the use of /FORCE:MULTIPLE) and in end ___argc and ___argv become unresolved.

So the basic question is: Can you link a DLL containing a CWinApp in VS10? How do you setup the linker to do it?

Comment: The definitions the linker is complaining about have nothing to do with CWinApp. (CException, for example, works fine in a DLL.) So while I don't know what your problem is, but that's not it.

Comment: Do you have a regular MFC DLL project or an extended DLL where you export the classes?

Comment: The class is not exported. This is in manner an MFC DLL. It is not an MFC application. There are no windows created or modified by the code. It was written 20 years ago by people who admit today they had no idea what they were doing. That's why my question is "can you put an app class in a DLL?" The class itself is only accessed from within the DLL (using AfxGetApp() and a lot of casting). Basically it was used as a hook for our trace library and as a way to store all the global data in a singleton class. What I want to do is get rid of the MFC stuff but I don't want to if I can get it to link

Answer (score 1):

> Can you link a DLL containing a CWinApp in VS10?

When I create a new project in Visual Studio 10 and use the MFC DLL template, I found the template code itself includes a class derived from CWinApp. Of course the template compiles and links fine, so the answer to this question is a most definite yes.

I searched for definitions to those objects that your linker is complaining about and I found them in afx.h and afxwin.h, inside Visual Studio's include directory, packaged with the rest of the ATL and MFC code that is included with Visual Studio when you install it.

Are you using the express edition by chance? One of the few differences between the express edition and the pro edition of Visual Studio 2010 is that ATL and MFC applications won't compile in the express edition. You have to use the pro edition.